# Centos 7 MongoDB fail to start after start up

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I'm trying to run MongoDB on my server. Running with Centos 7 and MongoDB 3.6.2.

After installation finished, I've reboot the server and found that the mongod service is not running.

The problem:
ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: Permission denied

So I've made some changes manually:

```
sudo touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo chcon system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo chown -R 995:992 /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

After this changes, the service is running.
After another reboot, the PID file is removed and not created alone.

Permissions for: /var/run/mongo directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x. mongod mongod system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /var/lib/mongo
```

/etc/mongod.conf:
processManagement:

```
fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Does anyone knows what can I do?

Thanks,
Yaniv